# Rails 3 - Using tags to associate photos with polymorphic Taggable class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tagging, polymorphic-associations

My goal is to create a system for associating photos with objects from any of several classes (Events, Organizations, Developments) using Tags.  For the life of me, I can't get this to work out, despite the fact that it seems like a pretty common situation.

*I'm relatively new to anything but the most basic Rails development, so I'm having a hard time forming the question. Please excuse any misnomers.*

Tag model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :photo_id, :taggable_id, :taggable_type

  belongs_to :photo
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Photo model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tags_attributes
  has_many :tags, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:taggable_id].blank? }
end
```

Event model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Organization model:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Development model:

```
class Development < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

In my Photo fields, I'm trying to use the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem to add tags to the photo (so I can later call those tagged objects in the photo's views, and the photo in the tagged object's views).

photos/new.html.erb (I have included the `nested_form` javascript)

```
<% nested_form_for @photo, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :tags do |tag_form| %>
    <%= tag_form.collection_select :taggable_id, Taggable.all, :id, :name %>
    <%= tag_form.link_to_remove "remove" %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add tag", :tags %></p>
  ...
  <% f.submit "Add photo" %>
<% end %>
```

**Is the structure of my models suitable for what I'm trying to do?**

and, if so,

**How can I properly specify both he :taggable_id and :taggable_type in my nested form?**

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your Photo model polymorphic and use something like attachment_fu / paperclip to upload photos.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attachment :content_type => :image,
                 :storage => :file_system,
                 :max_size => 2000.kilobytes,
                 :resize_to => '500x500>',
                 :thumbnails => { :thumb => '215x215>'}

  validates_as_attachment

  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable
end

class Development < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable
end
```

Your photos table should have attachable_id and attachable_type columns. With this you should be able to add photos to different object all stored in polymorphic photo model. Tagging also uses polymorphic associations and works in similar way. the documentation for the plugin would help. Hope that works for you.

Comment: Where do the tags come into play?  Unless I'm mistaken (a distinct possibility), this seems to handle tags and attachments independently of each other.  I'm looking for something more like `has_many :attachments, :through => :tags` (not sure I have that syntax correct, but close).  Set me straight, if you could... thanks!